# A very fast searchable file based Database

Tags: database

Anyone know a very fast file based database , for example http://www2.think-less-do-more.com/avafind/ it indexes entire hard disk (filenames ,attributes etc.. ) into an unknown file format, it searches very very fast, I am looking for a db like that , don't need relational one, just to simply store some text values, but needs to search it very fast.

I tried lucene its fast but any other ?

Comment: Its fine but i am interested in trying some other too.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene has a fast native c++ cousin with a perl wrapper - Kinosearch - (its on the cpan site)
Kinosearch is probably the fastest thing of its kind I've so far seen and has a nice easy perl wrapper.
(its made for use with perl but if you can run it as a daemon it can be quite easily modified to get php or other languages to talk to it via sockets)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is filebased but I don't know about its search speed. CouchDB could also be worth a look.